# Unclear statement in Shell sort algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop, shellsort

The 3rd statement of the innermost loop is unclear to me:

```
void shellsort(int v[], int n) 
{
    int gap, i, j, temp;

    for(gap=n/2;gap>0;gap/=2){
        for(i=gap;i<n;i++){
            for(j=i-gap;j>=0 && v[j]>v[j+gap];j-=gap) {
                temp=v[j];
                v[j]=v[j+gap];
                v[j+gap]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is `j` subtracted by `gap`? Doesn't it make `j` a negative value? For example if `j` was 0 and subtracted by, say 5...?

Comment: The logic for how `j` and `gap` are set ensures that it will never be negative.

Comment: Try adding a `printf` statement that shows the variables and you'll see it.

Comment: Re "*Doesn't it make `j` a negative value?*", It can, at which point the loop exits because of the `j>=0` check

Comment: "For example if j was 0 and subtracted by, say 5...?": then j becomes -5 and the inner loop exits. More worrying is the eventuality that gap becomes null, letting the inner loop run forever. But this is avoided by the condition gap>0.